# How does Javascript variable works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, var, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

Recently started learning Javascript.

Given an assignment for my class, to click a button (a number 10 is written on the button), and there has to be "Result = 55". (here all numbers from 0 to 10 are added)

To change words by clicking buttons, wrote code like this:

```
function myFunction(num) {
    var p = document.getElementById("mydata"); 
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        sum = sum + i; 
        p.innerHTML = "Result = " + sum;
    }              
}
```

After submitting assignment for school, learned that had to add `var sum = 0` above `var p = document.getElementById("mydata")`

However, do not understand what `var sum = 0` means. As for looks already show when to begin and end calculating, feel like it doesn't have to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var sum = 0;` declares a local variable named `sum`, and sets its initial value to `0`.

If you don't do this, when you do:

```
sum = sum + i;
```

the variable `sum` is initially undefined, and adding `i` to it results in `NaN` (Not a Number).

Some languages (e.g. PHP) automatically treat initialized variables as `0` in arithmetic expressions, but JavaScript doesn't do this, so you need to specify the initial value of the variable.

This has nothing to do with the way the `for` loop determines when to begin and end. It's about how to correctly add the numbers along the way.

It doesn't have to be before the `p` assignment, but it needs to be before the `for` loop.

Also, the line

```
p.innerHTML = "Result = " + sum;
```

doesn't need to be inside the loop. You should wait until the loop is done.